# Is $\frac{n-1}{n \bar{X}}$ a UMVUE?

Tags: statistics, variance, estimation, parameter-estimation

Consider $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ iid random sample from exponential distribution with pdf:
$$f(x,\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta x},\: x>0$$

I found that, $$E\left[\frac{n-1}{n\bar{X}}\right]=\theta$$

So $$\hat{\theta}=\frac{n-1}{n\bar{X}}$$ is an Unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

Also the Fisher information is $I(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2}$

The Cramer Rao Lower bound is $$Var(\hat{\theta})\ge \frac{\theta^2}{n}$$

Using the fact that $n\bar{X} \sim \Gamma(n, \theta)$

I found that $$Var(\hat{\theta})=\frac{\theta^2}{n-2}$$

So since the variance is not exactly CRLB, it is not efficient and hence not UMVUE?

But the solution here says it is UMVUE.
[Finding UMVUE of $\theta$ when the underlying distribution is exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034206/finding-umvue-of-theta-when-the-underlying-distribution-is-exponential-distri)

Comment: What happens if you try to Rao-Blackwellize this estimate?

Comment: UMVUE need not attain Cramer-Rao bound.

Comment: So you mean UMVUE need not be efficient?

Comment: By your definition of efficiency, it need not be efficient (for finite $n$).